# Using Multi language localization (Arabic, English)

Tags: android, locale

Using Multi language(Arabic,English) in Application.
If we set Arabic language as language in the app.For Numbers,Text view showing Arabic number.I want English numbers not Arabic number even if we selected English language.**how to show number in English even if language is in Arabic?**

Comment: put Your string and Numbers In formated String and use 
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="en">

Comment: Have you tried putting the numbers programmatically?

Comment: @Elsunhoty Thanks a lot,working fine.Please post it as answer.

Comment: Goal to help People Not to get Points  , Thanks

Comment: @Elsunhoty not for points,some one will come to know,which answer is correct.

Comment: ok i will do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default numbers are displayed in English only, unless you format the string, but it is not a good practice to use digits in English while using language that supports RTL specification. Please refer this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#FormatNumbers
It seems that you are changing language from device setting, please try changing language within the app, changing language from device setting will display numbers in that language.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.i am using custom font(Gotham.ttf).it taking number as Arabic digits based on localization.But for other font like myraidpro ,its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Ok

Just Try to put Your string and Numbers In formatted String and use this

something like this

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

and then

```
<resources xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; tools:locale="en">
```

Comment: where should I write `<resources xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; tools:locale="en">` this line?

Comment: Values ,,, Strings